# How to change the default hint value of XML fragment element in Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, google-places-api

Default hint value of the [autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) widget is `Search`. How can this value be changed to a different `String`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the below code:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment places= (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
EditText etPlace = (EditText)places.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input);
etPlace.setHint("Your Text");
```

Hope this helps.