# How to change the hint's text color of PlaceAutocompleteFragment?

Tags: android, placeautocompletefragment

I don't see any methods that I can use to change the text color of `hint` in `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`. [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43505879/3395198 . Just use `setHintTextColor`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EditText etPlace = (EditText)autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input);
        etPlace.setHint("Type your address");
        etPlace.setHintTextColor(R.color.primary_text_material_dark);
```

Comment: This solution won't work if we use `IntentBuilder` for showing the PlaceAutocomplete

Answer (score 0):

1. Add these files below to your project
2. add the `ThemedAutocompleteSupportFragment` instead of `AutocompleteSupportFragment` to your layout
3. modify the below `fragment_places_autocomplete.xml` to fit your app theme colors if needed. the important part is keep the `android:id` attributes as they are, so that the original `AutocompleteSupportFragment` can properly use them internally.

`ThemedAutocompleteSupportFragment.kt`

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment

class ThemedAutocompleteSupportFragment:AutocompleteSupportFragment()
{
    override fun onCreateView(inflater:LayoutInflater,container:ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState:Bundle?):View?
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_places_autocomplete,container,false)
    }
}
```

`res/layout/fragment_places_autocomplete.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layoutDirection="locale"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:textDirection="locale">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/places_autocomplete_search_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/places_autocomplete_search_hint"
        android:padding="@dimen/places_autocomplete_button_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        app:tint="?android:textColorSecondary" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/places_autocomplete_search_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="@string/places_autocomplete_search_hint"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/places_autocomplete_search_input_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/places_autocomplete_search_input_padding"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/places_autocomplete_search_input_text" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/places_autocomplete_clear_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/places_autocomplete_clear_button"
        android:padding="@dimen/places_autocomplete_button_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_clear_24"
        app:tint="?android:textColorSecondary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`res/drawable/ic_baseline_clear_24.xml`

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#000000"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z" />
</vector>
```

`res/drawable/ic_baseline_search_24.xml`

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#000000"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M15.5,14h-0.79l-0.28,-0.27C15.41,12.59 16,11.11 16,9.5 16,5.91 13.09,3 9.5,3S3,5.91 3,9.5 5.91,16 9.5,16c1.61,0 3.09,-0.59 4.23,-1.57l0.27,0.28v0.79l5,4.99L20.49,19l-4.99,-5zM9.5,14C7.01,14 5,11.99 5,9.5S7.01,5 9.5,5 14,7.01 14,9.5 11.99,14 9.5,14z" />
</vector>
```